# Storing language as multiple choice in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hi I am trying to get user's input of their spoken language from a multichoice field in form and store them into DB.

I was looking for a django module for languages but it seeems like there is no updated modules. So I decide to use the django settings. Get the input in list and store the joined value into a text field in DB.

`from django.conf import settings`

models.py

`language = models.TextField()`

forms.py

`language = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=settings.LANGUAGES)`

views.py

`myuser.language = ', '.join(form.cleaned_data['language']),`

I did a `print(', '.join(form.cleaned_data['language']))` right before I save the value into DB, it is returning "af, ar" but Somehow, when I retrieve the value after it is saved, it is giving me "('af, ar',)" instead of "af, ar".

Am I on the right track or there's a better way to achieve this?